# RequireJS: retry on script loading timeout

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I have a very huge script and sometimes require.js can't load it and throws a load timeout error.. Can requireJS make a retry? Or can it be performed in another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding:

```
waitSeconds : 0
```

To your require.config object.  This will set the time out on require to infinity.

You could adjust this figure based on your actual time out.

http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-waitSeconds

Comment: While this will improve upon the defaults for many mobile users or users on a slow connection, this still doesn't retry. Many problematic loads might require a retry to kick things off again vs just waiting longer.